# Python class instance starts method in new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I spent the last hour(s???) looking/googling for a way to have a class start one of its methods in a new thread as soon as it is instanciated.

I could run something like this:

```
x = myClass()

def updater():
    while True:
        x.update()
        sleep(0.01)

update_thread = Thread(target=updater) 
update_thread.daemon = True
update_thread.start()
```

A more elegant way would be to have the class doing it in **init** when it is instanciated.
Imagine having 10 instances of that class...
Until now I couldn't find a (working) solution for this problem...
The actual class is a timer and the method is an update method that updates all the counter's variables. As this class also has to run functions at a given time it is important that the time updates won't be blocked by the main thread.

Any help is much appreciated. Thx in advance...

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you tried to put that code in `MyClas.__init__`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can subclass directly from Thread in this specific case

```
from threading import Thread

class MyClass(Thread):
    def __init__(self, other, arguments, here):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.cancelled = False
        # do other initialization here

    def run(self):
        """Overloaded Thread.run, runs the update 
        method once per every 10 milliseconds."""

        while not self.cancelled:
            self.update()
            sleep(0.01)

    def cancel(self):
        """End this timer thread"""
        self.cancelled = True

    def update(self):
        """Update the counters"""
        pass

my_class_instance = MyClass()

# explicit start is better than implicit start in constructor
my_class_instance.start()

# you can kill the thread with
my_class_instance.cancel()
```

Comment: Beat me by half a minute. +1 for good answer. You should probably include at least the signature for the update method, since your answer looks like it's supposed to be a complete working piece of code. Also, it misses an import statement for `sleep`.

Comment: This works like a charm... Sometimes the solution is extremely simple. I had a similar approach but I couldn't get it running. Thanks so much... Sometimes I just can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run a function (or memberfunction) in a thread, use this:

```
th = Thread(target=some_func)
th.daemon = True
th.start()
```

Comparing this with deriving from `Thread`, it has the advantage that you don't export all of Thread's public functions as own public functions. Actually, you don't even need to write a class to use this code, `self.function` or `global_function` are both equally usable as `target` here.

I'd also consider using a context manager to start/stop the thread, otherwise the thread might stay alive longer than necessary, leading to resource leaks and errors on shutdown. Since you're putting this into a class, start the thread in `__enter__` and join with it in `__exit__`.